# Raise an event or return bool?

Tags: c#

I am wondering which is the most pragmatic option for a function that prints. lets say I have a printer and a print method like so.

```
 printerEngine.Print("StuffToPrint",Printer,Qty);
```

If something failed should I return a bool (in this case false) or raise a PrintingFailed event.

The printing failed event allows me to add more context as to why it failed but I am unsure as to the best way to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to fail with an exception, since something exceptional has happened to cause your print job to fail. You can include as much detail as you need in the exception and handle it where you need to. Maybe use a bool only if something happens that you expect that causes the job to fail.

Have a look at [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx) blog entry from Eric Lippert on exception handling, it is a good guide.

Comment: I accepted this answer because although it is the same as Jon Skeet's the link proved invaluable in making the final decision, cheers.

Comment: flattered to get the answer over Jon, who I have great respect for...thanks!

Comment: No problem, I would have went with Jon's if not for the Link you provided which I felt really cleared up some issues I had with pushing an exception, I ultimately went with TryPrint.

Answer (score 4):

Another obvious option is to throw an exception, just as you would if you were trying to write to a file or something similar.

That exception can have as much detail as you want, and you can let it bubble up the stack to the most appropriate place to handle it.

If the `Print` method is meant to be asynchronous, you may wish to consider returning a `Task` and let *that* indicate success, failure, completion etc (assuming you're using .NET 4).

Comment: Just wondering Jon, out of preference do you prefer to throw exceptions, or just put additional logic in to prevent them, then deal with the *logical anomalies* in a less *application-breaking* way? I always thought additional logic was best practice, based on what I've read/seen.

Comment: I would be interested to know the answer to this too.

Comment: I just made reference to [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx) from Eric Lippert on this subject - it is a good guide.

Comment: @mattytommo: It entirely depends on the context. Eric's blog is indeed good on this, unsurprisingly.

Answer (score 2):

That depends, do you want to provide why it failed to the user, or log it to some kind of log? If you want to do either of those, then raise then event.

If you want to do neither of those and you just want to determine if it failed or not, just use a `bool`.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a bool return value is too simple, and can't begin to enumerate all the problems that could happen. You could have some prebaked error codes... But that's still doesn't provide any context should you need it.

An event is ok. It allows you to return rich information. But both approaches will require completely different programming models though. And exception can be handled on the same stack thread that called it. An event would be called possibly in a completely different context. You may not have all the information available to properly treat a failure that you might have by using exceptions. 
So it's up to you to balance the trade-offs.